# Can we create a playbook to install a package in our own system?

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ubuntu Linux

I have created an inventory file and I have put my own system IP address there.

I have written a playbook to install the nginx package.

I'm getting the following error:

> false, msg" : Failed to connect to the host via ssh: connect to host myip : Connection refused, unreachable=true

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `hosts` keyword with the value `localhost`

```yaml
- name: Install nginx package
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: Install nginx package
    apt:
      name: nginx
      state: latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting your host IP directly in your inventory treats your local machine as  any other remote target. Although this can work, ansible will use the [`ssh` connection plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-ssh-connection) by default to reach your IP. If an ssh server is not installed/configured/running on your host it will fail (as you have experienced), as well as if you did not configure the needed credentials (ssh keys, etc.).

You don't need to (and in most common situations you don't want to) declare `localhost` in your inventory to use it as [it is implicit by default](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html). The implicit `localhost` uses the [`local` connection plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/local_connection.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-local-connection) which does not need ssh at all and will use the same user to run the tasks as the one running the playbook.

For more information on connection plugins, see the [current list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_connection.html)

See [@gary lopez answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68683176/9401096) for an example playbook to use `localhost` as target.